# Calling service discovery endpoint from an ECS instance [nginx, angular, express]

Tags: angular, express, nginx, devops, amazon-ecs

I have an angular application that uses nginx as a reverse proxy to connect to the backend server over the **/api** location. I have the angular application in a Docker container running on an ECS instance as a service, which binds the host port 80 to 8080 in the container.

I have launched the backend as also a container exposing 3000:3000 as a separate service through ECS. This time, I am using awsvpc to enable service discovery of this endpoint using an A record. I am rewriting the incoming url to remote the prefix: /api

Now, if I try and ping the backend service (using curl) from within the EC2 instance, I am able to receive the response. But, my angular application is not able to connect to the backend service. I think it is a configuration issue in the nginx.conf file (below):

```
worker_processes  2;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        root html/composite-app;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
            proxy_pass http://backend.local:3000;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Could anyone please point me in the right direction as to how I can debug this? I have been stuck on this for days now... I tried to use the bridge mode and hard code the ip address of the container (172.17.0.2:3000) and it worked perfectly. However, I want to use the service discovery route.

Comment: What does dig backend.local give you? Does it resolve IP correctly? If hard-cording ip in nginx conf gives you correct behaviour, this sounds more like a DNS issue.

Comment: Pinging backend.local from the ECS instance gives me the correct behavior. However, my frontend angular app is not able to connect to backend.local. Could you please give a sample running app which I launch to ECS and triage this further?